# Grails: Redirect from called method

Tags: grails, redirect

Good morning Community.

I use Grails for a backend app and therefore want to check if users are allowed to do the requested action.

So I call checkPermission() at the begin and redirect to the index page if user is not allowed. But I'm occuring this error:

*Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. A previous call to redirect(..) has already redirected the response.*

Extract from my source:

```
def test() {
  println("test()")
  checkPermission([TaskXYZ])
  println("AfterCheck")
  redirect(action: "profile", params: [lang: params.lang])
}    

private checkPermission(def tasks) {
  println("checkPermission()")
  if ( ! userService.isAllowed(tasks)) {
    println("NotAllowed")
    flash.error = message(code: "msg.actionIsNotAllowed")
    redirect(action: "index", params: [lang: params.lang])
    return false
  }
}
```

Output:

```
test()
checkPermission()
NotAllowed
AfterCheck
```

So the redirect doesn't work from the private method and return false causes the return to the called method.

What can I do alternatively? I considered beforeInterceptor, but I need to pass custom parameters for every method.

Thanks,
Rob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is that issuing a redirect doesn't stop the execution of the controller method/action. After your `redirect` within `checkPermission` your controller code continues to execute after `checkPermission` and is encountering the next `redirect`. You need to `return` from your controller if your `checkPermission` is to terminate the execution of the controller method/action.

For example:

```
...
private boolean checkPermission(def tasks) { ... }
...
if (!checkPermission([TaskXYZ])) return
...
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't call redirect() method twice during one request, though that's what your code is doing, but you can simply change it in numerous ways, i.e.

```
def test() {
  boolean hasPermission = checkPermission([TaskXYZ])
  if (!hasPermission) {
      return ; // you have to finish the action, because you already called redirect inside checkPermission() method
  }
  // do further actions when permission granted
  redirect(action: "profile", params: [lang: params.lang])
}    

private checkPermission(def tasks) {
  if ( ! userService.isAllowed(tasks)) {
    return false
  }
  return true
}
```

you could also improve it so that you can make different redirects:

```
def test() {
  boolean checkPermissionResult = checkPermission([TaskXYZ])
  if (checkPermissionResult != null) {
      return redirect(checkPermissionResult)
  }
  // do further actions when permission granted
  redirect(action: "profile", params: [lang: params.lang])
}    

private checkPermission(def tasks) {
  if ( ! userService.isAllowed(tasks)) {
    return [action: "index", params: [lang: params.lang]]
  } else if (userService.userNotExists()) { // or any different situatoin
    return [action: "register", params: [lang: params.lang]]
  }
  return null
}
```